# Mongoose : How will I get 5 random records with 5 different conditions?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, database

My model : Question (Only data relevant to question are given all other things are removed)

```
exports = module.exports = function(app, mongoose) {
  var questionSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    difficultyLevel: {
        type: String,
        enum: ['easy', 'medium', 'hard']
    },
    questionType: {
        type: String,
        enum: ['Type1', 'Type2', 'Type3']
    },
    questionText: {
        type: String,
        trim: true
    }
  });
  questionSchema.plugin(require('./plugins/pagedFind'));
  questionSchema.set('autoIndex', (app.get('env') === 'development'));
  app.db.model('Questions', questionSchema);
};
```

And I have around 250+ Questions in my DB.

My requirement : I need 5 RANDOM questions, were first and second question should be of "Type1", third question should be of "Type2", fourth should be "Type3" and fifth should be "Type1"

My idea to implement it :

```
async.parallel({
    Type1: function(callback) {
        Question.find({}, {
            questionType: "Type1"
        }).limit(3).exec(function (err, questions) {
            callback(null, questions)
        })
    },
    Type2: function(callback) {
        Question.find({}, {
            questionType: "Type2"
        }).limit(1).exec(function (err, questions) {
            callback(null, questions)
        })
    },
    Type3: function(callback) {
        Question.find({}, {
            questionType: "Type3"
        }).limit(1).exec(function (err, questions) {
            callback(null, questions)
        })
    },
},
function(err, results) {
    // Take all results here order it as per requirement and return
    //results.Type1, results.Type2, results.Type3
    // return the result in required order.
})
```

But I know this is not the efficient way to do it. As it executes 3 queries and after that the order also has to be changed.

Question : What is the best/better way to do it?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways to do this. The easiest way is to [skip()](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.skip/) a random number of documents and then use [limit(1)](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.limit/) to get a document from the collection.

If you're skipping a lot of documents, this can be expensive.

Another solution is to generate a unique integer field (something like auto increment in MySQL) for each question type and query on that field.